# How to calculate return rates with negative prices?

Tags: options, volatility, black-scholes, asset-returns

I'm dealing with electricity options and I'm considering the possibilty of negative prices. I want two estimate the historic volatility. However, an arithmetic mean doesn't feel appropriate and $\log(\frac{P_i}{P_{i-1}})$ doesn't work if $P_{i-1}$ is less or equal than 0.

For example:

20th July:  $P_1$= 24 euros/MWh
21st July:  $P_2$= -70 euros/MWh

what do you suggest to properly calculate the return rate? what is the correct interpretation?

Comment: There is no negative prices even in electricity options. But aside that I second what Hebe suggested. Use simple returns rather than log returns.

Comment: Is P the price or the return?

Comment: Yes, P is the price. Electricity, in some markets, can achieve negative prices.

Comment: You mean you are paid to consume electricity? Then we must be dealing with markets where the laws of supply and demand do not apply and hence conventional methods and models should not be applied either. But out of curiosity can you please share with us where that is the case and why?

Comment: some electricity markets allow energy prices to become negative. Although counter-intuitive, the justification is based on the fact that with steep demand variations, it becomes cheaper to the power generators to simply pay someone to consume the electricity than decrease the level of production or even to shut down the power plant.

Comment: here is an example at EEX platform:  http://www.eex.com/en/Market%20Data/Trading%20Data/Power/Hour%20Contracts%20|%20Spot%20Hourly%20Auction/Hour%20Contracts%20Chart%20|%20Spot%20Hourly%20Auction/spot-hours-chart/2013-07-22/EU/-/1y

Comment: I do not agree with your rational behind  your argument nor have I ever heard of suppliers paying to have electricity consumed. At worst they could give it away for free. While I have never traded power there is no apparent logical reason why power prices could ever be negative while there are many good reasons why interest rates may be negative. Have you checked that your chart observation is not just a data error?

Comment: There is no real 'law' of supply and demand because humans are irrational. They probably pay you because they need to get rid of the electricity very badly. Characteristics of electricity which are very important: non-storability and inelasticity of demand.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what model you assume for the underlying. The situation, that the underlying can become negative also occures for interest rate spreads and even for interest rates. Here some people use absolute changes, that is $X_{i} - X_{i-1}$ instead of relative changes $\frac{X_{i} - X_{i-1}}{X_{i-1}}$ or (which is almost the same as relative returns) log-returns $\log(\frac{X_{i}}{X_{i-1}})$

If you model the return as normal distributed, you are assuming that your underlying is log-normal. Hence you estimate vol from log-returns.

If you model the absolute changes as normal distributed, you would estimate the historic vol from absolute changes.

Since you are speaking of options and vol, you should know what your model assumption is.

PS: More details on this can also be found in http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2194917

Comment: I'm assuming log normality of the underlying, and threfore, as you said, I should estimate from the log-returns but can´t used them because it may occur Pi/Pi-1<0. And I don't think the absolute changes are suitable for this problem. Therefore I may be out of alternatives

Comment: If $P_{i}/P_{i-1} < 0$, then the assumption of log-normality is clearly wrong. You should consider an alternative model. Why do you think that absolute changes are not suitable? Why do you believe in log-normality so strongly? You may also consider a displaced log-normal model, like in the cited paper. If data with $P_{i}/P_{i-1} < 0$ is just a rare sample error, you may consider leaving that data out. Put it appears as if this is not the right way here...

Comment: Basically I'm estimating the volatility in order to determine the option value according to Black-Scholes and compare it to the empirical value and then analyze the differences, that's why I'm tried to use log normal returns

Comment: if I use the absolute values, what meaning does the volatility hold?

Comment: Black-Scholes seems to be not adequate. A displaced model may be more adequate. Of course, you may calculate an implied BS vol. What is your heeding strategy? What does your hedge do if prices are negative? The answers to these question should give the you the option prices. Not the blind believe in an inappropriate model...

Comment: Exactly, I second what Christian said. It seems you try to force data into distributional nomenclature just to be able to apply an option pricing model of your own choosing rather than the other way around. But you still have not explained why a producer would pay money to deliver electricity rather than just "dump it" and why consumers would receive money for power consumption. I am afraid there is a misunderstanding on your end going on.

Comment: Matt Wolf: Negative prices (or huge positive spikes) are regularly happening in electricity spot markets since electricity is almost non-storable and production must equal consumptions at all times, otherwise the power grid would become unstable and lots of bad things would happen. Most power plants cannot regulate their output fast enough in non-emergency situations. The electricity grid is full of various supplementary power-balancing services reacting to changes in supply/demand in matter of hours and even minutes to seconds.

Comment: @airguru, I understand all that. But negative prices make no sense. Why cant power suppliers not simply pump surplus into the grid which they in fact do all the time as far as I heard. They constantly generate an oversupply and as far as I heard they would never pay anyone for such oversupply. In fact they already incur the cost without being able to sell it. Could you please think of an example where power prices are clearly demonstratively negative? I am honestly curious.

Comment: @MattWolf: You can very accurately imagine electricity network (alternating current) as a huge interconnected spinning shaft. Some are actively spinning it, some are just connected and use its spin to power their devices. The shaft turns 50 times per second precisely (60 in US), and all devices are adapted to this frequency and will not function properly if the frequency changes significantly. This analogy is very accurate also in the sense, that there is no clear "power flow". Averyone is just connected to common "shaft" ...

Comment: ... The shaft spinning is directly connected to the power plant turbines, so if there is more producers than consumers, the shaft will start spinning more rapidly. If there is more consumers than producers, the shaft spinning will slow down. This unbalance can literally cause power plant turbines to slow down/halt, since they cannot overcome the load. And of course, different shaft spinning frequencies will break connected devices. Therefore, huge effort is devoted to all kinds of balancing mechanisms, that will keep the shaft spinning at the same rate all the time ...

Comment: ... To ensure this balance, electricity is traded hourly in auctions, where the exchange tries to exactly match supply to demand based on the bids and offers of participants. It literally intersects supply and demand curves (see http://www.apxgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/marketdata/powernl/public/aggregated_curves/Hour16.gif ). Horizontal axis is quantity, vertical is price. Red is supply, blue is demand. You can see, that some buyers are willing to buy at whatever cost. These are utilities, that cannot adjust their consumption to price. This sometimes produces huge positive price spikes...

Comment: ... On the other hand, you can see that some suppliers are willing to supply at whatever cost, just because when you have your powerplant running, you cannot fully stop it in the matter of few minutes. Therefore you simply must sell you electricity, and someone must consume it. Sometimes (usually on holiday nights) this produces negative price spikes. As Joao already linked: http://www.eex.com/en/Market%20Data/Trading%20Data/Power/Hour%20Contracts%20%7C%20Spot%20Hourly%20Auction/Hour%20Contracts%20Chart%20%7C%20Spot%20Hourly%20Auction/spot-hours-chart/2013-07-22/EU/-/1y

Comment: @aiguru, interesting. Thanks for that illustration. It is just I thought we live in 2013 and power plants can easily use technology to reduce the produced energy directed to the grid, in fact that is something every household appliance can handle: A variable input of power but a converter that can variably reduce the consumed power depending on settings. Why is that not available on a grand scale?

Comment: @MattWolf: Some plants can do this, like gas-fired, which are basically aircraft jet engines. Just control the fuel valve. But they have quite expensive fuel. If you take coal plants: The beast eats several trains full of coal each day. Huge fire that you must feed/extinguish. It takes several hours for coal plant to ramp up/down. Same for nuclear power. They are designed for continuous operation. Of course, everything has safe emergency shutdown, but then you can throw most stressed parts away. It's the matter of wear of pipes, shafts, boilers, that suffer from changes in temperature/load.

Comment: @aiguru, I was not talking about an alteration in supply. I am talking about some sort of "load-balancer". You supply it with constant amount x (constant over some defined period) and it balances out short term variations in demand y by outputting x -> y where the balance exits the circuit rather than overloading the grid.

Comment: @MattWolf:One does not simply exit the circuit.It's real energy that has to be dumped somewhere.Suppose you have full-throttled car. You don't want it to go anywhere, so you lift it off the road (disconnected demand),but you also don't want engine to reach high rpm.You must somehow consume the excess power. You can for example brake the wheels. Then you are dumping the power in the form of heat.Or use it for pumping water to reservoir,or something else.That's exactly how the balancing services work. What we really need is good batteries.Good storage results in smoother prices (see gas market).

Comment: how about xi-1 is zero

Answer (score 1):

Abandon the idea to use lognormal (GBM) model for power spot market. Just don't do it. Spot power prices have totally different properties and Black-Scholes option prices will not make any sense. They won't be even remotely close to the correct option value!

Just a list of things that lognormal model does not capture and that are important for option pricing:

- Negative prices
- Price spikes (stochastic volatility)
- Mean reversion
- Strong periodicity (daily, weekly, yearly)
- Impossibility to hedge small products for sufficiently long time

Answer (score -1):

In this case,you shouldn't use log return.You should calculate return as (P(i)/P(i-1))-1.

Comment: Defining || as the absolute value, wouldn't it be more suitable to make an adaptation and use (Pi-Pi1)/|Pi-1|??  because if P1=-20 and P2=-10 you are not losing more money

Comment: @Hebe: Which does not work if P(i-1) is zero. Actually (P(i)/P(i-1))-1 is just a finite difference approximation of the log-return.

Comment: @Joao Serafim: This does not solve the explosion for $P_{i-1}$ becoming close to zero. You won't consider wiggeling around zero as such a huge vol, or do you?

Comment: @Christian Fries: Definitely not. But how can I solve that issue?

Comment: same to, how solve it when the pi-1 is zero